# Calendar view: Making year+month exposed filter go to the right URL

Tags: uri, views, datetime

Using the calendar module, I've created a monthly calendar:

> > [image: Monthly calendar]

The built-in navigation using << Prev and Next >> links works great, and correctly navigate to the previous and next month, using URLs like: 
http://example.com/calendar?field_event_date_value[value][year]=&field_event_date_value[value][month]=&date=2014-07

The 2nd navigation is the year + month select lists. I got a requirement to navigate directly to a specific year and month using a dropdown selection. So I've added an exposed filter on the "Event: start date" field (see screen below), which tries to do it but the URL gets broken on the way. I get: http://example.com/calendar?field_event_date_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Byear%5D=2014&field_event_date_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Bmonth%5D=7. However, even if I manually fix the URLs displays empty data.

[image: Monthly exposed date filter]

I tried to put a custom date selection form using [this tip](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73857/get-value-for-drupal-date-pager-next-or-prev-or-current), but the form doesn't print. I also tried to create a custom submit handler [like this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22989/changing-url-of-exposed-filter/23061#89757) in order to create a custom redirect but views behavior doesn't change. Also, [changing the form action](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4583/how-to-redirect-an-exposed-filter-query-to-a-views-results-page-that-lives-in-an) doesn't work since the target of the redirect depends on the user's selection and it still appends the extra query parameters.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I dunno but I ended up just doing it all manually with markup and JS, probably is an easier way but yeh:

```
<select id="month" name="month">
  <option id="01" value="January">January</option>
  <option id="02" value="February">February</option>
  <option id="03" value="March">March</option>
  <option id="04" value="April">April</option>
  <option id="05" value="May">May</option>
  <option id="06" value="June">June</option>
  <option id="07" value="July">July</option>
  <option id="08" value="August">August</option>
  <option id="09" value="September">September</option>
  <option id="10" value="October">October</option>
  <option id="11" value="November">November</option>
  <option id="12" value="December">December</option>
</select>

<select id="year" name="year">
</select>

<button id="gotomonth">Go</button>


$('#gotomonth').click(function() {
  var month = $("#month option:selected").attr('id');
  var year = $("#year option:selected").attr('id');
  location.href = year + '-' + month;
});

var currentMonth = ("0" + (new Date().getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
for (i = (currentYear - 3); i < (currentYear + 3); i++) {
  $('#year').append('<option id="' + i + '" value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
}
$('#month #' + currentMonth).attr("selected", "selected");
$('#year #' + currentYear).attr("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: I had to change this line of code in your example to make it work: `location.href = Drupal.settings.basePath + 'VIEW_URL/' + year + '-' + month;` Also notice you can use the function date_month_names() to get the current language version of each month.